# Types in conditional always false

Tags: powershell, types, conditional-operator

I am trying to pass an exception type to be ignored to a function, but also provide a default exception type to ignore. And that default is not working. So, given

```
function Test {
    param (
        [Type]$ExceptionType = [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException]
    )

    if ($ExceptionType -is [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException]) {
        Write-Host "Yes"
    } else {
        Write-Host "No: $ExceptionType"
    }
}
```

I would expect that running

```
Test
```

would return `Yes` because of the default value. But running

```
Test -ExceptionType:([System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentOutOfRangeException])
```

should return `No: System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentOutOfRangeException`, which is does.

The problem is somehow in the conditional, because

```
if ([System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException] -is [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException]) {}
```

also returns false. But elsewhere, where `$PSItem.Exception` is the exception I am evaluating the ignore on,

```
if ($PSItem.Exception -is $waitOnExceptionType) {}
```

seems to work fine. So, what am I doing wrong, and why is the conditional not working in this case? I have also tried wrapping the type in `( )` as you have to do with the argument, as well as using a second variable for the conditional, like so

```
$defaultException = ([System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException])
if ($ExceptionType -is $defaultException) {
```

But to no avail.

Hmm, I suspect I have bigger problems. Per @mathias-r-jessen I have revised to

```
if ($ExceptionType -eq ([System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException])) {
    Write-Host "Yes"
} else {
    Write-Host "No: $($ExceptionType.GetType().FullName)"
}
```

And now the conditional works with the default, but when passing

```
Test -ExceptionType:([System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentOutOfRangeException])
```

I return `No: System.RuntimeType` rather than the correct type. So anything I do later that depends on the actual type is problematic.

Comment: The type of `$ExceptionType` will always be `[type]`, you want `$ExceptionType -eq ...` rather than `$ExceptionType -is ...`

Comment: Stop calling `GetType()` on `$ExceptionType` - the variable _already contains a type_ :)

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen Good to understand that better. I have the conditional working with the default type now, but when a different type is passed, it seems to be cast to  `System.RuntimeType`.

Comment: You're confusing _the type of_ the stored type literal with the stored type literal itself.

Comment: Ah, got it now. Just let the type be cast to string to get feedback on the passed type.

Comment: Not necessarily, invoke `FullName` if that's what you want, just don't call `GetType` _on the type literal itself_. Change `$ExceptionType.GetType().FullName` to `$ExceptionType.FullName`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-is` operator is for testing whether a given value is *an instance of a type*.

To test whether a given type is a subclass of another, use [the `Type.IsSubclassOf()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.issubclassof?view=net-7.0):

```
$ignoredBaseType = [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException]

if($ExceptionType -eq $ignoredBaseType -or $ExceptionType.IsSubClassOf($ignoredBaseType)){
    # ignore ...
}
```